# The result of multiplying two double varibles is zero, why?

Tags: java, double, multiplication

I have a problem when I multiply two 'double' variables in my program, the result I get is zero. why?

for example:

```
1.0E-321 * 5.321777473676208E-4 = 0.0
```

how to prevent the result is not zero?.

Comment: `double` has a [minimum value](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#MIN_VALUE). If you try and store a number smaller than that, you get [underflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_underflow).

Comment: is there any solution?

Comment: Use `BigDecimal`.

Comment: There's the [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`double` has a [minimum value](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#MIN_VALUE). If you try and store a number smaller than that, you get [underflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_underflow).

You could use the [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class.

```
BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("1.0E-321");
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("5.321777473676208E-4");
System.out.println(a.multiply(b));
```

Answer (score -2):

Double has a maximum and a minimus value (somewhere around -1.7*10^308) and since ur calulation has a result that approximates to 5.3 E325 it shows an error u can try multipying the numbers first and then the exponents for eg 
1*5.32177 and then simply add the powers (-321 +(-4)) thus u can get ur answer. :)